# Facebook comments plugin not loading

Tags: facebook-comments

I'm using Facebook comments Plugin on one of my page (WordPress Driven) and it was working but suddenly it stopped loading. I didn't change anything and I can see those codes present at the page. It happened several times, sometimes work and suddenly stops. I've added xml name space at the html tag and placed the code right after body opening tag, at first the root div and then js. Can anyone please check it out at http://heera.it/who and it's at the bottom of the page. Thanks !

Comment: Right after I've posted the question it's showing again and still now I didn't change anything. What's going on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without using a plugin. Just make your own.

Find this line: `<?php comments_template(); ?>` in the file (in theme) you want to add a comment facebook. (exm. wp-content -> themes -> YourTheme -> single.php)

Copy and paste the following code above the line above:

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="YOUR WEBSITE LINK" data-num-posts="2" data-width="628"></div>
<?php comments_template(); ?>
```

Comment: I'm not using any plugin and not using it for article commenting, instead it's on my "Who I AM" page and it's now working but not sure how long it'll remain. Thanks, anyway! Here is the link http://heera.it/who

Comment: This record of your page load time.

`[13:29:18.805] GET https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?api_key=214579588612813&channel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D3%23cb%3Df3312d3cc50b0b2%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fheera.it%252Ff15e8aec80e968e%26relation%3Dparent...[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 15199ms]`

`[13:37:45.978] GET https://www.facebook.com/plugins..[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 19636ms]`

it seems the problem is not on your website, but the response from the facebook servers are slow, so the ajax loading times out, maybe facebook is a high bandwidth traffic.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so what do you think, I'm doing fine or nothing my fault at all ?

Comment: :) U r doing fine & your coding is also fine. btw there is a little mistake in your ccs, `#post-wrap {width: 980px; margin: 0 auto;f}` , 'f' letter after `..auto;` . I hope your days fun :D